# Function name is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, django

Searched a lot of question with the same error but nothing helped.

Am using Python/Django and here the HTML code am trying to make it work.

here is my code:

```
 <tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">
 <td class="sorting_1">
{{ item.book_name }}
</td>
 <td>{{ item.book_subject }}
</td>
<td>{{ item.book_level }}
</td>
<td>{{ item.book_teacher }}
</td>
<td><input type="number" id="price_{{ item.id }}" style="width: 50px;"/>
</td>
<td><input type="number" id="commission_{{ item.id }}"style="width: 50px;"/>
</td>
<td>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_button" onclick="addingTheBook_{{ item.id }}()">
إضافة
</button>
</td>
</tr>
<script>
function addingTheBook_{{ item.id }}() {
var the_price = document.getElementById('price_{{ item.id }}');
var the_commission = document.getElementById('commission_{{item.id}}');
window.location.href = '/vip/add/pricelist/' + {{ item.id }} +'/' + the_price.value + '/' + {{ current_vip }} +'/' + the_commission.value + '/';
                                            }
                                        </script>
```

Whenever I click the button with onclick attribute, it gives me the error `addingTheBook_3 is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. Are you using some kind of framework to replace the items in brackets? If so, please [edit] your question to include that framework's tag.

Comment: is this angular? I ask because you are using double braces '{{' in what I think might be your template code, but you don't use ng-click. Regardless I suspect the function does not exist because you can not access item.id from within the script tag like that. perhaps what you want is something like this in the html/template? <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_button" onclick="addingTheBook({{ item.id }})"> and something like this in the js function addingTheBook(id) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function as:

```
function addingTheBook_(itemId){
}
```

And use the itemId variable to fetch price, commission, etc. like below:

```
var the_price = document.getElementById('price_'+ itemId);
var the_commission = document.getElementById('commission_'+itemId);
```